# Problems with frying chicken...coating doesnt stick, and coating doesnt get crispy

Tags: chicken, frying

Ive been trying to fry chicken in oil, but im running into issues with the coating.

Ive tried using a pre-made coating mix and flour. I coat the chicken in egg (which is supposed to help the coating to stick) then coat the chicken in the coating. But the coating struggles to stick to the chicken and falls off when i flip the chicken over. It also hardens and turns into solid pieces that stick to the bowl and which i cant use, which is a waste of the coating.

The coating doesnt get really crispy when I fry the chicken in oil either. It only gets mildly crispy, not like the crunchy type you get in restaurants or KFC's hot n spicy chicken.

The flour does get somewhat crunchier when fried though, compared to using the coating mix only.

Does anyone know why the coating mix/flour is struggling to stick to the chicken (even when I coat the chicken in egg first) and why its not getting really crispy?

Edit : Just tried to fry chicken again, didnt use egg this time. The coating didnt turn into hard pieces, but the coating didnt stick to the chicken. The flour/coating also mostly dissolved upon contact with the oil. Not sure what im doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

oh the trick is to first dip the chicken in flour, then egg, then coating mix. If you have some time, give the coating 10-15 seconds to settle while it's in your hand.

You also need to double fry the piece of chicken, start at a lower time until the chicken cooks, around 300, cool for 2-3 minutes, then turn it up to 375-425 depending on the batter until it's brown.

Comment: Just tried to fry chicken again, didnt use egg this time. The coating didnt turn into hard pieces, but the coating didnt stick to the chicken. The flour/coating also mostly dissolved upon contact with the oil. Think the egg making the chicken wet is causing the coating to turn into hard pieces and stick to the bowl.

Comment: try the flour -> egg -> flour, it really makes a difference, I have no idea why

Answer (score 0):

One thing that worked for me is, using egg wash instead of egg (aka thinning the egg with a few tbs of liquid).  The egg by itself was too thick, it clung to itself instead of sticking to the food so there wasn't enough remaining on the surface to keep the breading on.

I don't know if this will help crispiness - it might, having a better breading coat to begin with, and being able to fry it longer without everything falling off, or it might not depending on what the problem is.